# Filter completed events by using end time filter (greater than or equal to 'now')

Tags: views, javascript

I'm almost done with integrating the Fullcalendar module into my website, but I am concerned about the loading time. I have about 200 events, and getting even more which are repeated daily, weekly, monthly. It's impossible to load all these events initially, since it requires tons of queries, and I got a time-out error from Apache. They cannot be cached either.

What I want to do to improve it is initialize the full calendar view in day-view mode, then just fetch the events in the next 7 days, and disable the completed events. Take a look at the date field table, I saw one repeating event will be divided into entities that have their own start and end date for each day, so guess it's possible to filter them out by a view date filter.

[image: screenshot]

I added a view filter as the attached image.  Output query is correct.

[image: screenshot]

The result just remained the same: It displayed the events in the past and in the far future.

[image: screenshot]

I've already tested this filter with an ordinary view and get the expected results. So I'm kind of sure the issue only comes from the module code. For some reasons it doesn't apply the filter. I have been spending several days on examining the code, but didn't have any luck yet. Anyone experienced this or has a better idea to improve the loading time please leave some words. I'd appreciate any time spent on this topic.

You can view my full view at http://citypassguide.com/vietnam-deals.